# .install file not creating table in drupal

Tags: drupal-7

Hi i am very new in drupal. i just create a module that create a form with some inputs. I wrote .install file for the same but it is not creating table. While i am installing this module it is neither showing error nor install table.

```
function mycontact_schema() {
     $schema['mycontact'] = array(
        'description' => t('This table for mycontact.'),
        'fields' => array(
          'mycontctid' => array(
            'description' => t('The primary identifier for a mycontact.'),
            'type' => 'serial',
            'unsigned' => TRUE,
            'not null' => TRUE),
          'vid' => array(
            'description' => t('The current {mycontact_revisions}.vid version identifier.'),
            'type' => 'int',
            'unsigned' => TRUE,
            'not null' => TRUE,
            'default' => 0),
          'name' => array(
            'description' => t('The {mycontact_name} of this mycontact.'),
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'length' => 32,
            'not null' => TRUE,
            'default' => ''),
          'email' => array(
            'description' => t('The name of this contact, always treated a non-markup plain text.'),
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'length' => 255,
            'not null' => TRUE,
            'default' => ''),
          ),
          'comments' => array(
            'description' => t('The comments of this contact, always treated a non-markup plain text.'),
            'type' => 'text',
            'not null' => TRUE,
            'default' => ''),
        'primary key' => array('mycontctid'),
        );
        return $schema;
    }
It is not showing any error and any warning.
```

Comment: how do you uninstall it? Just disable it? Try 'Un installing' it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in the hook_install implementation.
I followed these steps to get it working:

1. Created a directory called `mycontact` inside `sites/all/modules`.
2. Created a the files `mycontact.info`, `mycontact.module`, and `mycontact.install`.
3. Inside `mycontact.info` I added the following lines:

   ```
   name = my contact
   core = 7.x
   ```
4. And in the `mycontact.install` file, I copied all the code from the question as it is.
5. Left the `mycontact.module` file empty. *Note:* Drupal needs this empty file.
6. Enabled the module. And it worked!

What you could do now is, disable the module -> uninstall it -> follow the above steps to install the module; and you should have your database table created for you.

Comment: Why i need to leave empty .module file. what i did created mycontact.info file put information in this. created mycontact.module file enable it. and check my form it is working fine. After that i create .install file and disable module and enable again, form is looking fine but table is not created in database.

Comment: @innovativeKundan not necessary to keep the file empty. I was just trying to emphasize that drupal needs this file.

Comment: The `hook_schema` only gets fired when the module is *installed* and not every time it is *enabled*. To create the table, you should *uninstall* the module after disabling it. And the enable it again to trigger the hook.

Comment: Yeh.. thanx @Ajit s actually i did the same and it works. I uninstall module and install it again. Thanks Ajit s. Like it